# Is there a package for moving screen instead of cursor?

Tags: package, scrolling

I am using emacs for a few months now and it is going ok.

I want to know if there is a package out there which can help me move the screen instead of my cursor.

For example, if I move one line down(Ctrl n) then instead of the cursor going one line down I want the screen to scroll up on line. This way my cursor is always in the middle and the text moves instead of cursor.

I want this behavior because I think it will be easier on my eyes.

Is this possible? Any leads appreciated.

Comment: How about `centered-cursor-mode`?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/centered-cursor-mode.el  How about using the mouse wheel?  See also the commands `scroll-up` and `scroll-down`.  The mouse wheel can be adjusted to scroll-up/down just one line or many lines at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I like these, although I only have the first two bound right now:

```
(defun kb-scroll-up-hold-cursor ()
  "Scroll up one position in file."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up-command 1))

(defun kb-scroll-down-hold-cursor ()
  "Scroll down one position in file."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up-command -1))

(defun kb-scroll-up ()
  "Scroll up one position in file, move cursor with the scroll."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up-command -1)
  (forward-line -1))

(defun kb-scroll-down ()
  "Scroll down one position in file, move cursor with the scroll."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up-command 1)
  (forward-line 1))

(bind-key "M-P"  'kb-scroll-up-hold-cursor)
(bind-key "M-N"  'kb-scroll-down-hold-cursor)
```